# What is the data format for the lambdaMART in xgboost (Python version)?

Tags: python, ranking, xgboost

I have a dataset in the libsvm format which contains the label of importance score and the features.
qid is the query. The data is showed below.

I want to use xgboost to make a search rank but I dont know what is the input data format for the xgb.train function. I have seen the data format used for classification and regression. But my dataset has the query which represent the group information and the lambda has not yet been calculated. So How can I use xgboost api to train my rank model and what is the format of data needed?

Besides, I want to use ndcg to evaluate my model.

Many thanks and I am looking forward the solution.

```
0 qid:1830 1:0.002736 2:0.000000 3:0.000000 4:0.000000 5:0.002736 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
0 qid:1830 1:0.025992 2:0.125000 3:0.000000 4:0.000000 5:0.027360 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
0 qid:1830 1:0.001368 2:0.000000 3:0.000000 4:0.000000 5:0.001368 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
1 qid:1830 1:0.188782 2:0.375000 3:0.333333 4:1.000000 5:0.195622 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
1 qid:1830 1:0.077975 2:0.500000 3:0.666667 4:0.000000 5:0.086183 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
0 qid:1830 1:0.075239 2:0.125000 3:0.333333 4:0.000000 5:0.077975 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
1 qid:1830 1:0.079343 2:0.250000 3:0.666667 4:0.000000 5:0.084815 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
1 qid:1830 1:0.147743 2:0.000000 3:0.000000 4:0.000000 5:0.147743 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
0 qid:1830 1:0.058824 2:0.000000 3:0.000000 4:0.000000 5:0.058824 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
0 qid:1830 1:0.071135 2:0.125000 3:0.333333 4:0.000000 5:0.073871 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
1 qid:1840 1:0.007364 2:0.200000 3:1.000000 4:0.500000 5:0.013158 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
1 qid:1840 1:0.097202 2:0.000000 3:0.000000 4:0.000000 5:0.096491 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
2 qid:1840 1:0.169367 2:0.000000 3:0.500000 4:0.000000 5:0.169591 6:0.000000 7:0.000000 8:0.000000 9:0.000000 10:0.000000
......
```

Answer (score 2):

[Format in XGBoost docs](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/input_format.md#group-input-format)

Generally of the form:

```
<line> .=. <target> <feature>:<value> <feature>:<value> ... <feature>:<value> # <docid> <inc> <prob>
<target> .=. +1 | -1 | 0 | <float> 
<feature> .=. <integer> | "qid"
<value> .=. <float>
<info> .=. <string> 
<inc> .=. <integer> 
<prob> .=. <float> 
<docid> .=. <string>
```

See [dump_svmlight_file](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file.html) if you would like to write your data in that format.